# Comparing 2 equations (algorithms): $A = 8n^2 +32n\lg n, B = 256n\lg n + 128n\lg\lg n$

Tags: inequality, algorithms

I have 2 algorithms that the number of calculations they do can be represent as equations:

*NOTE: The base of the $log$ i use is $2$ namely: $\lg n = \log_2 n$

$$
A = 8n^2 +32n\lg n
$$

$$
B = 256n\lg n + 128n\lg\lg n
$$

I need to decide for which values of $n$, algorithm $A$ wins on $B$ (namely, satisfies $A<B$)

The answer takes each part of the algorithms and compares.

For example for the first part of each algorithm we get: 
$$
C_A(n) = 8n^2, C_B(n) = 256n\lg n
$$

Now they took:
$$
n=2^k, k=0,1,2,...
$$

They got:

$$
C_A(n) < C_B(n), \forall n = 2^k, 0 < k < 8
$$

I tried to calculate:

$$
8n^2 = 256n\lg n \Rightarrow n = 2^5\lg n 
$$

I don't know how to continue to get the answer...

Help.

Thanks.